# How do I send multiple API request once?

Tags: dart, flutter, axios, flutter-dependencies

currently, I used `http`, I found a way to send multiple requests once to react using axios.

```
axios.all([
    axios.get('http://google.com'),
    axios.get('http://apple.com')
  ])
  .then(axios.spread((googleRes, appleRes) => {
    // do something with both responses
  });
```

Like this Is that any way to send multiple requests once?

Comment: Is it must simultaneously or in sequence?

Comment: simulateneously

Comment: I need to fetch data to cache

Comment: Ok, I'm writing the code.

Comment: omg...Thanks a lot.. currently I used `await storeFirstApiData();` after that `await storeSecondApiData();` like this.. So much time to cache

Answer (score 0):

@mezoni answer is correct. But this is less code with caching also.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  final urlList = ['http://google.com', 'http://apple.com'];

  final responses = await Future.wait(
    urlList.map((String url) {
      return http.get(url);
    }),
  );

  final List<dynamic> caches = responses.map((response) {
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }).toList();
}
```

Comment: you got multiple APIs data.but how to use on sqlite? I mean how to store these two APIs data on two sqlite tables?

Comment: Can to answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/56629955/8822337