# Optimal way to request multiple APIs and store on SQLITE multiple tables

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-http

**Question is: how to store on sqlite? I mean how to store 2 APIs data on 2 tables?**

I have multiple APIs to get and store data on the cache. currently, I do it one by one, like this:

*button pressed():*

```
 await HelperDatabase1().storeRegister(_url, tokens);
 await HelperDatabase1().storeEquipmentReg(_url, tokens);
...
```

It's slow down my app...So I decided do @günter-zöchbauer way. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50028061/9139407) But I don't understand How to store on SQLite in multiple tables.

**`storeAll()` used `Future.wait`**

```
void storeAll(String url, String token) async {
  final urlList = ['$url/nativeapi/v1.0/Register','$url/nativeapi/v1.0/EquipmentReg'];

  final responses = await Future.wait(
    urlList.map((String url) {
      return http.get(url,headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'});
    }),
  );

  final List<dynamic> caches = responses.map((response) {
    print('store All: ${response.body}');
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }).toList();
}
```

**print is working well**

**Below two methods use on currently**
`storeRegister()` method(**get data and store local**)

```
storeRegister(String url, String token) async {
    var db = await db1;
    Batch batch = db.batch();
    final response = await http.get(
      '$url/nativeapi/v1.0/Register',
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'},
    );
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    AssetRegister model = AssetRegister.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    int length = model.data.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      var data = DataRegister(
          i: model.data[i].i,
          d: model.data[i].d,
          c: model.data[i].c,
          u: model.data[i].u,
          p: model.data[i].p,
          a: model.data[i].a);
      batch.insert(
        'registerTable',
        data.toMap()
      );
    }
    await batch.commit();
  }
```

`storeWquipmentReg()` method

```
  storeEquipmentReg(String url, String token) async {
    var db = await db1;
    Batch batch = db.batch();
    final response = await http.get(
      '${url}/nativeapi/v1.0/EquipmentReg',
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}'},
    );
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    Assets model = Assets.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    int length = model.data.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      var data = DataEquipmentReg(
        i: model.data[i].i,
        r: model.data[i].r,
        l: model.data[i].l,
        t: model.data[i].t,
        p: model.data[i].p,
        c: model.data[i].c,
        u: model.data[i].u,
        a: model.data[i].a,
        b: model.data[i].b,
        eq_no: model.data[i].eq_no,
        isH_wit_C: model.data[i].isH_wit_C,
        n: model.data[i].n,
      );
      batch.insert(
        'EquipmentRegTable',
        data.toMap()
      );
    }
    await batch.commit();
  }
```

Comment: @mathronaut can answer this question bro

Comment: I'm busy right now, I'll answer your answer tonight with an example code bro.

Comment: please.. thanks a lot bro.

Comment: Change (( final List<Map<String, dynamic>> caches => final List<dynamic> caches )). What is the question about below two methods?

Comment: @mathronaut question is: how to store on sqlite? I mean how to store 2 APIs data on 2 tables?

Comment: it's really helpful question. please someone answer it. he need to call multiple apis and store on local db.

Comment: @günter-zöchbauer please help him sir

Comment: The code you are trying is looking okay, if you share your error log it will be very helpful.

Comment: @mathronaut it's not any error. ```final List<dynamic> caches = responses.map((response) {
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }).toList();``` in here got APIs data. but how to store on cache?(I used sqflite).. I added i current code also

Comment: so you want to merge storeAll method with storeRegister, storeWquipmentReg methods?

Comment: storeRegister and storeEquipmentReg is curretly I used method. No need to use this methods. storeAll() method I got all APIs data, but how to store on tables? like storeRegister and storeEquipmentReg

Comment: @mathronaut can use tables array like apis arrays

Comment: you mean, is it possible to saving arrays into tables?

Comment: yes, and how to do it?